# Can I target in CSS a single line element?

Tags: css

I need to be able to differentiate within the css between an element with a single line and one with multiple lines - can it be done?

(I cannot break the lines into different DOM elements, it's always one element with 1 or more lines)

Comment: No, you can't do that with css

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: I have a title that should be placed next to a bullet - if it's 2 lines or more the title should be vertically aligned to the top of the bullet, but if the title is only 1 line it should be vertically centered. 

can it be done without JS?

Comment: maybe with some code and a better explanation of what you try to do, you would get some tips. As is your question , answer is just no :(

Comment: okay, how do you generate this bullet ? any HTML to show :)  http://codepen.io/anon/pen/aNqyBd ?

Comment: the bullet is just another html element
<div><i class='bullet'></i><span>the text content</span></div>

Comment: something like this ? http://codepen.io/anon/pen/aNqyBd

Comment: not really, what I am trying to do is where the bullet behaves more like drop caps for the text (but in case the paragraph is only one line - center the line vertically in alignment to the bullet)